# Openssl CMS encrypt in ruby

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl, rsa

I have a task which requires encrypting a big chunk of data in ruby. Encryption should be done as follows.

1. Generate a random key.
2. Encrypt the data with generated random key and in AES_256_CBC encryption.
3. Encrypt the random key with the receipt's public key.
4. Envelope all this information using CMS and send it to recipient.

I could perform AES encryption and RSA encryption using OpenSSL ruby library using documentation provided below.
http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html

But there is no documentation on how to use OpenSSL CMS in ruby.

Question 2:

When I am running openssl commandline tool. It is giving an error that CMS is not a valid command. OpenSSL version is "OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013". 
Do I need to install any extra packages to get CMS support?

Comment: Full CMS support was added in OpenSSL 1.0.0 and I don't think it was backported to the 0.9.8 series. Unfortunately even if you compile Ruby against a newer OpenSSL I don't believe it has bindings for the CMS_* methods. If you need to use Ruby (and control both sides of this equation) you could consider using PKCS7 signing (PKCS7 v1.5 is the predecessor to CMS)

Comment: Thanks Paul Kehrer. Recipient is using Java and BouncyCastle and I do not have control over recipient side code.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't dealt with this myself, but I use the [backup gem](https://github.com/meskyanichi/backup) which provides what you want.
Take a look at the project and see if you really need to implement yourself or you can use the gem. If you need to implement yourself, you can always take a look at the code and see how it's done.